# How to get rows, by group, of data frame with earliest timestamp?

Tags: r, dplyr

```
df <- data.frame(group=c(1,2,4,2,1,4,2,3,3),
             ts=c("2014-02-13","2014-06-01","2014-02-14","2014-02-11","2013-02-01","2014-02-02","2014-03-21","2014-12-01","2014-02-11"),
             letter=letters[1:9])
df$ts <- as.Date(df$ts,format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

I want to find an operation that will produce the complete rows containing the minimum timestamp per group, in this case,

```
group         ts letter
    1 2013-02-01      e
    4 2014-02-02      f
    2 2014-02-11      d
    3 2014-02-11      i
```

A quick and dirty (and slow) base R solution would be

```
dfo <- data.frame(df[order(df$ts,decreasing=F),],index=seq(1:nrow(df)))
mins <- tapply(dfo$index,dfo$group,min)
dfo[dfo$index %in% mins,]
```

Intuitively, I think if there was a way to add an order index by group then I could just filter to where that column's value is 1, but I'm not sure how to execute it without lots of subsetting and rejoining.

Comment: You didn't specify how you want to handle ties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(df, group) %>% summarise(min = min(ts), letter = letter[which.min(ts)]) 
#   group        min letter
# 1     1 2013-02-01      e
# 2     2 2014-02-11      d
# 3     3 2014-02-11      i
# 4     4 2014-02-02      f
```

You could also `slice` the ranked rows

```
group_by(df, group) %>% 
    mutate(rank = row_number(ts)) %>% 
    arrange(rank) %>%
    slice(1)
```

Comment: `letter` could also be computed with `letter = letter[which.min(ts)]`. This also has the advantage of not throwing an error if there are ties for the minimum.

Comment: @PatrickMcCarthy, If you don't want to retype the column names, you can also use the following dplyr option `group_by(df, group) %>% filter(ts %in% min(ts))` or use dplyr's rank functions if you want to handle ties.

Comment: @DavidRobinson - good call, thanks.  I've edited to show that.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a data.table solution. You seem to want the result orders by `ts`, not `group`. THis does that.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,.SD[which.min(ts)],by=group][order(ts)]
#    group         ts letter
# 1:     1 2013-02-01      e
# 2:     4 2014-02-02      f
# 3:     2 2014-02-11      d
# 4:     3 2014-02-11      i
```

Comment: I gave Richard the point since I did technically ask for dplyr, however I like your solution a lot better as I don't need to manually redefine all the columns.

Comment: Other than the tag, your question does not mention `dplyr`. The data.table solution will be *much* faster, but the dataset would have to be really large (>1e5 records) to notice it.

Comment: Could make it even faster using `setorder` for data.table v <=1.9.4 `setorder(setDT(df)[,.SD[which.min(ts)],by=group], ts)[]` Though generally `.SD[]` subsetting is not so optimized

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner using base R.

```
df[sapply(split(df,df$group), function(x) row.names(x)[which.min(x$ts)] ),]
```

Breaking it down some:

```
list.by.group <- split(df,df$group)
#a vector of the row names corresponding to the earliest date in each group
names.of.which.min <- sapply(list.by.group, function(x) row.names(x)[which.min(x$ts)])
#subset the data frame by row name
df[names.of.which.min,]
```